# How to compare two dates in d-M-Y format?

Tags: php, date, compare

Please could you tell me what is wrong in this code ?

```
$locked_date = date('d-M-Y');
$edit_date = '29-Apr-2013';
if($edit_date <= $locked_date){
echo $edit_date.' smaller then'. $locked_date;
}
else {
echo $edit_date.' bigger then'. $locked_date;
}
```

Comment: That's not how you do date comparisons; you're currently comparing two strings to see which is sorted first alphabetically.

Comment: String comparison is by `character`, left to right, and `"29-Apr"` > `"23-May"` because `"9"` > `"3"`

Comment: To add to what @andrewsi has noted.  You either need to change these to unix timestamps for a numerical comparison, or your a date format  like `'Y-m-d'` that functions properly with a string comparison.

Comment: Actually its showing wrong answer.. its showing 29-Apr-2013 bigger then 23-May-2013 but its should show: 29-Apr-2013 smaller then 23-May-2013

Comment: right, because, as @MarkBaker said, 9 > 3. the month doesn't even factor into the comparison. if it was 23-Apr and 23-May, then it would sort april before may

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**strtotime**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function which will convert it to Unix Timestamp,

```
if(strtotime($edit_date) <= strtotime($locked_date)){
    echo $edit_date.' smaller then'. $locked_date;
}
else {
   echo $edit_date.' bigger then'. $locked_date;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare dates formatted as strings like that. An easy way to check if a date occurs before or after another date is to convert them to Unix timestamps (which are just integers) first using `strtotime`:

```
$locked_date = date('d-M-Y');
$edit_date = '29-Apr-2013';

if(strtotime($edit_date) <= strtotime($locked_date)) {
    echo $edit_date.' smaller then'. $locked_date;
} else {
    echo $edit_date.' bigger then'. $locked_date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime` function to compare unix timestamps:

```
$locked = time(); //current timestamp
$locked_date = date(d-M-Y);
$edit_date = '29-Apr-2013';
$edit = strtotime($edit_date);
if($edit <= $locked){
    echo $edit_date.' smaller then'. $locked_date;
}
else {
    echo $edit_date.' bigger then'. $locked_date;
}
```

Comment: this won't give the desired output as the dates are always integer timestamps.